# Selenium is not identifying the 'iframe'

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Below in my code

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("file")));
```

Above line is not running

Comment: below are the source code

Comment: Please post HTML code snippet and complete code of the frame you are trying to work on.

Answer (score 0):

There is various way to switch to frame. Please share the HTML code if you need a exact code to switch to your respective application. you can try with below method. Better use index if your frame do not any name etc

```
driver.switchTo().frame(index)
```

replace index with 0 first and if it not work then try with 1 and then 2 etc one by one

More details

`driver.switchTo().frame()` has multiple overloads.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(name or id)
```

Here your iframe doesn't have id or name, so not for you.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(index)
```

This is the last option to choose, because using index is not stable enough as you could imagine. If this is your only iframe in the page, try

`driver.switchTo().frame(0)`

```
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe_element)
```

The most common one. You locate your iframe like other elements, then pass it into the method.

Here locating it by title attributes seems to be the best.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[title='Fill Quote']")));
// driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//iframe[@title='Fill Quote']")));
```

Answer (score 0):

most probably, your iframe is not visible or your window is not active.

in Python:

```
    driver.switch_to_default_content()
    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("yourFrame"))
```

in Java:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.tagName("yourFrame")));
```